# OnItemLongClickListener() doesn't result in log tap gesture in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, contextual-action-bar, long-press, uilongpressgesturerecogni

Long tap gesture not working in ListFragment in combination with **AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener**. I'm trying to achieve the GMail like long-tap selection and continuous selection on upcoming single taps.

The ListFragment declared as below:

```
public class VacationListFragment extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener, 
    ActionMode.Callback, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, 
    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener, {
```

ListFragment loads the data from DB with SimpleCursorAdapter as below:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vacationlist_row_item, null, 
                  fromColumns, toView, 0);
mVacationListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Current scenario:

on single the CAB shows up with provided menu(delete) and the action is working. Screenshot pasted below:

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3NMh.png)

I believe we're very close to solution and any input would be appreciated.
Feel free to ping if I'm not pedagogical. Thanks.

Comment: Found the best example from below link:

https://github.com/springbyexample/spring-by-example/blob/master/android/android-client/src/main/java/ua/com/springbyexample/fragment/MainListFragment.java

Hence the quest solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue with below code sample. It's Good example for Multi-select list for **ListFragment** in conjunction with **LoaderCallbacks** and **MultiChoiceModeListener**.

https://github.com/springbyexample/spring-by-example/blob/master/android/android-client/src/main/java/ua/com/springbyexample/fragment/MainListFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

Sample :

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                /*do action */
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `mVacationListView.setOnLongClickListener(this)` into your code. Then you will be able to handle clicks using:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Current listener implementation 

`mSpamListView = getListView(); mSpamListView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty)); mSpamListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL); mSpamListView.setItemsCanFocus(false); mSpamListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); mSpamListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); mSpamListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this); `

Comment: It should be not in listener but in onCreateView or onAttach

Answer (score 0):

I think you want list item click in your fragment. Please try below code.

1. Add this code in your adapter.

   ```
   mVacationListView.setOnLongClickListener(your fragment instance);
   ```
2. Handle override method in your fragment.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       return false;
   }
   ```

If you do like this then your list item long click listener will handle at your fragment.

Comment: can you refer any sample which I can made use of. Thanks

Comment: Hi faisalm please check below link. Sample code also available.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html